# I get this Error AttributeError at /listings/5689-resot-relly-market, 'Profile' object has no attribute 'favourite' please any help would be apprciate

Tags: python, django

I'm working a add to favourite function in django and i keep getting this error when i hit the save button. everything looks fine from here that why i can't really tell where the error is coming from

**Models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    favorite = models.ManyToManyField(Accomodation, related_name='profile')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mis-spelt **favourite**
so i changed this line

`favorite = models.ManyToManyField(Accomodation, related_name='profile')`

to

`favourite = models.ManyToManyField(Accomodation, related_name='profile')`